# How to print in mapReduce using mongodb node package

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the mongodb package for node.js. I have a `mapReduce` function, and I would like to print some debug output inside of it. How do I do this?

I currently have the following:

```
var map = function() {
  print('hello');
  emit('key', 1);
}

var reduce = function(k, vals) {
  return Array.sum(vals);
}

collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: {inline: 1}}, function(err, results) {...});
```

However, `hello` never gets printed to the console when I run from the command line:

```
$ node test.js
```

How do I see the output?

Answer (score 0):

Replace [`print`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/#print) with [`console.log`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console). node.js has a [`console`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console) object like the browser environment.

```
var map = function() {
  console.log('hello');
  emit('key', 1);
}
```

[`print`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/#print) is for the mongodb shell.

Comment: I'm actually looking for something that works through the command line. When I use `console.log` inside a `mapReduce`, it gives and error: `exception: ReferenceError: console is not defined`